# xCode6 - cannot compile brand new project

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm running into a weird issue, where upon creating a new project (single view app) I cannot build it due to the following warnings.

Prior to seeing the error:

- I dragged a bunch of libraries from one project to a new project, including UIKit.
- Then the project did not compile and I deleted these libraries using "Send to trash" option.
- I re-added these libraries using "link binary with libraries" option.
- The project does not compile.
- Upon visiting the trash folder I do not have the "Put back" option for most of the deleted libraries.

  **What could be the root cause of not being able to build a brand new xCode project?** Can I actually accidentally delete the root libraries though some xCode user error? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some important files.  Perhaps re-install XCode?

Comment: Existing projects compile normally.